# Internet Explorer website is trying to close this page, click yes or no

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a popup created using jQuery, window.open() function. the popup works fine in all browsers except IE. In IE it popups another annoying confirmation with message "Internet explorer website is trying to close this page, click yes or no". if clicked yes, the popup closes because I have `self.close()` at the end of code. But entire webpage is messed up. If i click no, entire browser closes down. How do I remove this confirmation message using jQuery for IE?

jQuery

```
(function($){

    $.oauthpopup = function(options)
    {
        if (!options || !options.path) {
            throw new Error("options.path must not be empty");
        }
        options = $.extend({
            windowName: 'ConnectWithOAuth'
          , windowOptions: 'location=0,status=0,width=800,height=400'
          , callback: function(){ window.location.reload(); }
        }, options);

        var oauthWindow   = window.open(options.path, options.windowName, options.windowOptions);
        var oauthInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
            if (oauthWindow.closed) {
                window.clearInterval(oauthInterval);
                options.callback();
            }
        }, 1000);
    };

    //bind to element and pop oauth when clicked
    $.fn.oauthpopup = function(options) {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.click($.oauthpopup.bind(this, options));
    };
})(jQuery);
```

After authentication of popup I am redirecting it to a page where it has

```
<script>self.close()</script>
```

for closing the popup.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for info

Comment: Do you control the code on the page that opens the popup? If so, you can close the popup from the page that created it, which usually works.

Comment: @Markasoftware Yes popup is opened using an on click event

Comment: Please provide a minimal working code snippet so we have with what to work.